# No Module After Install Package via Canopy Package Management

Tags: python, pyodbc, canopy

I need help with the pyodbc Python module. I installed it via Canopy package management, but when I try to import it, I get an error (no module named pyodbc). Why?

Here's the output from my Python interpreter:

> > > import pyodbc
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import pyodbc
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc

Comment: what is your output from "import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)" ?

Comment: Just saw your support ticket, will respond further there.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I will update in support ticket

Answer (score 0):

For the record: the attempted import was in a different Python installation. It is never good, and usually impossible, to use a package which was installed into one Python installation, in another Python installation.